# How to get list of softlayer's operatingSystemReferenceCode?

Tags: java, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using softlayer api using the [Java implementation](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java) to create multiple VMs from different locations with different operating systems.

But I need a way to know the list of available `operatingSystemReferenceCode` and Datacenter code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the SoftLayer Python CLI with `pip install softlayer` and from the command line type:

```
$ slcli vs create-options
```

It will return a long list of the ***current*** options for OS's available including the Datacenter codes:

```
$ slcli vs create-options

:................................:.................................................................................:
:                           name : value                                                                           :
:................................:.................................................................................:
:                     datacenter : ams01                                                                           :
:                                : ams03                                                                           :
:                                : che01                                                                           :
:                                : dal01                                                                           :
:                                : dal05                                                                           :
:                                : dal06                                                                           :
:                                : dal09                                                                           :
:                                : dal10                                                                           :
:                                : dal12                                                                           :
:                                : dal13                                                                           :
:                                : fra02                                                                           :
:                                : fra04                                                                           :
:                                : fra05                                                                           :
:                                : hkg02                                                                           :
:                                : hou02                                                                           :
:                                : lon02                                                                           :
:                                : lon04                                                                           :
:                                : lon06                                                                           :
:                                : mel01                                                                           :
:                                : mex01                                                                           :
:                                : mil01                                                                           :
:                                : mon01                                                                           :
:                                : osl01                                                                           :
:                                : par01                                                                           :
:                                : sao01                                                                           :
:                                : sea01                                                                           :
:                                : seo01                                                                           :
:                                : sjc01                                                                           :
:                                : sjc03                                                                           :
:                                : sjc04                                                                           :
:                                : sng01                                                                           :
:                                : syd01                                                                           :
:                                : syd04                                                                           :
:                                : tok02                                                                           :
:                                : tor01                                                                           :
:                                : wdc01                                                                           :
:                                : wdc04                                                                           :
:                                : wdc06                                                                           :
:                                : wdc07                                                                           :
:             flavors (balanced) : B1_1X2X25                                                                       :
:                                : B1_1X2X25                                                                       :
:                                : B1_1X2X100                                                                      :
:                                : B1_1X2X100                                                                      :
:                                : B1_1X4X25                                                                       :
:                                : B1_1X4X25                                                                       :
:                                : B1_1X4X100                                                                      :
:                                : B1_1X4X100                                                                      :
:                                : B1_2X4X25                                                                       :
:                                : B1_2X4X25                                                                       :
:                                : B1_2X4X100                                                                      :
:                                : B1_2X4X100                                                                      :
:                                : B1_2X8X25                                                                       :
:                                : B1_2X8X25                                                                       :
:                                : B1_2X8X100                                                                      :
:                                : B1_2X8X100                                                                      :
:                                : B1_4X8X25                                                                       :
:                                : B1_4X8X25                                                                       :
:                                : B1_4X8X100                                                                      :
:                                : B1_4X8X100

...continued...

:                                : C1_16X16X100                                                                    :
:                                : C1_16X16X100                                                                    :
:                                : C1_32X32X25                                                                     :
:                                : C1_32X32X25                                                                     :
:                                : C1_32X32X100                                                                    :
:                                : C1_32X32X100                                                                    :
:               flavors (memory) : M1_1X8X25                                                                       :
:                                : M1_1X8X25                                                                       :
:                                : M1_1X8X100                                                                      :
:                                : M1_1X8X100                                                                      :
:                                : M1_2X16X25                                                                      :
:                                : M1_2X16X25                                                                      :
:                                : M1_2X16X100                                                                     :
:                                : M1_2X16X100                                                                     :
:                                : M1_4X32X25                                                                      :
:                                : M1_4X32X25                                                                      :
:                                : M1_4X32X100                                                                     :
:                                : M1_4X32X100                                                                     :
:                                : M1_8X64X25                                                                      :
:                                : M1_8X64X25                                                                      :
:                                : M1_8X64X100                                                                     :
:                                : M1_8X64X100                                                                     :
:                                : M1_16X128X25                                                                    :
:                                : M1_16X128X25                                                                    :
:                                : M1_16X128X100                                                                   :
:                                : M1_16X128X100                                                                   :
:                                : M1_30X240X25                                                                    :
:                                : M1_30X240X25                                                                    :
:                                : M1_30X240X100                                                                   :
:                                : M1_30X240X100                                                                   :
:                                : M1_48X384X25                                                                    :
:                                : M1_48X384X25                                                                    :
:                                : M1_48X384X100                                                                   :
:                                : M1_48X384X100                                                                   :
:                                : M1_56X448X25                                                                    :
:                                : M1_56X448X25                                                                    :
:                                : M1_56X448X100                                                                   :
:                                : M1_56X448X100                                                                   :
:                                : M1_64X512X25                                                                    :
:                                : M1_64X512X25                                                                    :
:                                : M1_64X512X100                                                                   :
:                                : M1_64X512X100                                                                   :
:                  flavors (GPU) : AC1_8X60X25                                                                     :
:                                : AC1_8X60X100                                                                    :
:                                : AC1_16X120X25                                                                   :
:                                : AC1_16X120X100                                                                  :
:                                : ACL1_8X60X100                                                                   :
:                                : ACL1_16X120X100                                                                 :
:                cpus (standard) : 1,2,4,8,12,16,32,56                                                             :
:               cpus (dedicated) : 1,2,4,8,16,32,56                                                                :
:          cpus (dedicated host) : 1,2,4,8,12,16,32,56                                                             :
:                         memory : 1024,2048,4096,6144,8192,12288,16384,32768,49152,65536,131072,247808            :
:        memory (dedicated host) : 1024,2048,4096,6144,8192,12288,16384,32768,49152,65536,131072,247808            :
:                    os (CENTOS) : CENTOS_5_64                                                                     :
:                                : CENTOS_6_64                                                                     :
:                                : CENTOS_7_64                                                                     :
:                                : CENTOS_LATEST                                                                   :
:                                : CENTOS_LATEST_64                                                                :
:                os (CLOUDLINUX) : CLOUDLINUX_5_64                                                                 :
:                                : CLOUDLINUX_LATEST                                                               :
:                                : CLOUDLINUX_LATEST_64                                                            :
:                    os (COREOS) : COREOS_CURRENT_64                                                               :
:                                : COREOS_LATEST                                                                   :
:                                : COREOS_LATEST_64                                                                :
:                    os (DEBIAN) : DEBIAN_6_64                                                                     :
:                                : DEBIAN_7_64                                                                     :
:                                : DEBIAN_8_64                                                                     :
:                                : DEBIAN_9_64                                                                     :
:                                : DEBIAN_LATEST                                                                   :
:                                : DEBIAN_LATEST_64                                                                :
:            os (OTHERUNIXLINUX) : OTHERUNIXLINUX_1_64                                                             :
:                                : OTHERUNIXLINUX_LATEST                                                           :
:                                : OTHERUNIXLINUX_LATEST_64                                                        :
:                    os (REDHAT) : REDHAT_5_64                                                                     :
:                                : REDHAT_6_64                                                                     :
:                                : REDHAT_7_64                                                                     :
:                                : REDHAT_LATEST                                                                   :
:                                : REDHAT_LATEST_64                                                                :
:                    os (UBUNTU) : UBUNTU_12_64                                                                    :
:                                : UBUNTU_14_64                                                                    :
:                                : UBUNTU_16_64                                                                    :
:                                : UBUNTU_18_64                                                                    :
:                                : UBUNTU_LATEST                                                                   :
:                                : UBUNTU_LATEST_64                                                                :
:                  os (VYATTACE) : VYATTACE_6.5_64                                                                 :
:                                : VYATTACE_6.6_64                                                                 :
:                                : VYATTACE_LATEST                                                                 :
:                                : VYATTACE_LATEST_64                                                              :
:                       os (WIN) : WIN_2003-DC-SP2-1_32                                                            :
:                                : WIN_2003-DC-SP2-1_64                                                            :
:                                : WIN_2003-ENT-SP2-5_32                                                           :
:                                : WIN_2003-ENT-SP2-5_64                                                           :
:                                : WIN_2003-STD-SP2-5_32                                                           :
:                                : WIN_2003-STD-SP2-5_64                                                           :
:                                : WIN_2008-STD-R2-SP1_64                                                          :
:                                : WIN_2008-STD-SP2_32                                                             :
:                                : WIN_2008-STD-SP2_64                                                             :
:                                : WIN_2012-STD-R2_64                                                              :
:                                : WIN_2012-STD_64                                                                 :
:                                : WIN_2016-STD_64                                                                 :
:                                : WIN_LATEST                                                                      :
:                                : WIN_LATEST_32                                                                   :
:                                : WIN_LATEST_64                                                                   :
:                    san disk(0) : 25,100                                                                          :
:                    san disk(2) : 10,20,25,30,40,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,350,400,500,750,1000,1500,2000 :
:                    san disk(3) : 10,20,25,30,40,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,350,400,500,750,1000,1500,2000 :
:                    san disk(4) : 10,20,25,30,40,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,350,400,500,750,1000,1500,2000 :
:                    san disk(5) : 10,20,25,30,40,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,350,400,500,750,1000,1500,2000 :
:                  local disk(0) : 25,100                                                                          :
:                  local disk(2) : 25,100,150,200,300                                                              :
: local (dedicated host) disk(0) : 25,100                                                                          :
: local (dedicated host) disk(2) : 25,100,150,200,300,400                                                          :
: local (dedicated host) disk(3) : 25,100,150,200,300,400                                                          :
: local (dedicated host) disk(4) : 25,100,150,200,300,400                                                          :
: local (dedicated host) disk(5) : 25,100,150,200,300,400                                                          :
:                            nic : 10,100,1000                                                                     :
:           nic (dedicated host) : 100,1000                                                                        :
:................................:.................................................................................:
```

... for bare metal the options are hardware specific so you have to do:

```
$ slcli server chassis-list
```

which returns the chassis identifiers then for the one you want type:

```
$ slcli server create-options 41
```

Another way is to exhaustively examine the SoftLayer API services and data type documents ... http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account. There's also documentation here https://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.org/en/v2.3.1/_modules/SoftLayer/managers/hardware/#HardwareManager.get_dedicated_server_create_options

Answer (score 3):

http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/Getting-Started-Python-CLI

```
$ slcli vs create-options

:.................:.....................................................................................................................................:
:           Name : Value                                                                                                                            :
:.................:.....................................................................................................................................:

    ***:    datacenter : wdc01,sjc01,sea01,dal01,dal05,dal06,dal09,hou02,sng01,lon02,ams01,ams03,hkg02,tor01,mel01,par01,mex01,tok02,fra02,syd01,mon01,mil01 :***

:  cpus (private) : 1,2,4,8                                                                                                                             :
: cpus (standard) : 1,2,4,8,12,16                                                                                                                       :
:       memory : 1024,2048,4096,6144,8192,12288,16384,32768,49152,65536                                                                             :
:   os (CENTOS) : CENTOS_5_32                                                                                                                       :
:               : CENTOS_5_64                                                                                                                       :
:               : CENTOS_6_32                                                                                                                       :
:               : CENTOS_6_64                                                                                                                       :
:               : CENTOS_7_64                                                                                                                       :
:               : CENTOS_LATEST                                                                                                                     :
:               : CENTOS_LATEST_32                                                                                                                  :
:               : CENTOS_LATEST_64                                                                                                                  :
: os (CLOUDLINUX) : CLOUDLINUX_5_32                                                                                                                     :
:               : CLOUDLINUX_5_64                                                                                                                   :
:               : CLOUDLINUX_6_32                                                                                                                   :
:               : CLOUDLINUX_6_64                                                                                                                   :
:               : CLOUDLINUX_LATEST                                                                                                                 :
:               : CLOUDLINUX_LATEST_32                                                                                                              :
:               : CLOUDLINUX_LATEST_64                                                                                                              :
:   os (DEBIAN) : DEBIAN_6_32                                                                                                                       :
:               : DEBIAN_6_64                                                                                                                       :
:               : DEBIAN_7_32                                                                                                                       :
:               : DEBIAN_7_64                                                                                                                       :
:               : DEBIAN_8_32                                                                                                                       :
:               : DEBIAN_8_64                                                                                                                       :
:               : DEBIAN_LATEST                                                                                                                     :
:               : DEBIAN_LATEST_32                                                                                                                  :
:               : DEBIAN_LATEST_64                                                                                                                  :
:   os (REDHAT) : REDHAT_5_32                                                                                                                       :
:               : REDHAT_5_64                                                                                                                       :
:               : REDHAT_6_32                                                                                                                       :
:               : REDHAT_6_64                                                                                                                       :
:               : REDHAT_7_64                                                                                                                       :
:               : REDHAT_LATEST                                                                                                                     :
:               : REDHAT_LATEST_32                                                                                                                  :
:               : REDHAT_LATEST_64                                                                                                                  :
:   os (UBUNTU) : UBUNTU_10_32                                                                                                                      :
:               : UBUNTU_10_64                                                                                                                      :
:               : UBUNTU_12_32                                                                                                                      :
:               : UBUNTU_12_64                                                                                                                      :
:               : UBUNTU_14_32                                                                                                                      :
:               : UBUNTU_14_64                                                                                                                      :
:               : UBUNTU_LATEST                                                                                                                     :
:               : UBUNTU_LATEST_32                                                                                                                  :
:               : UBUNTU_LATEST_64                                                                                                                  :
:   os (VYATTACE) : VYATTACE_6.5_64                                                                                                                     :
:               : VYATTACE_6.6_64                                                                                                                   :
:               : VYATTACE_LATEST                                                                                                                   :
:               : VYATTACE_LATEST_64                                                                                                                :
:       os (WIN) : WIN_2003-DC-SP2-1_32                                                                                                             :
:               : WIN_2003-DC-SP2-1_64                                                                                                              :
:               : WIN_2003-ENT-SP2-5_32                                                                                                             :
:               : WIN_2003-ENT-SP2-5_64                                                                                                             :
:               : WIN_2003-STD-SP2-5_32                                                                                                             :
:               : WIN_2003-STD-SP2-5_64                                                                                                             :
:               : WIN_2008-DC-R2-SP1_64                                                                                                             :
:               : WIN_2008-DC-SP2_64                                                                                                                :
:               : WIN_2008-ENT-R2-SP1_64                                                                                                            :
:               : WIN_2008-ENT-SP2_32                                                                                                               :
:               : WIN_2008-ENT-SP2_64                                                                                                               :
:               : WIN_2008-STD-R2-SP1_64                                                                                                            :
:               : WIN_2008-STD-SP2_32                                                                                                               :
:               : WIN_2008-STD-SP2_64                                                                                                               :
:               : WIN_2012-DC-R2_64                                                                                                                 :
:               : WIN_2012-DC_64                                                                                                                    :
:               : WIN_2012-STD-R2_64                                                                                                                :
:               : WIN_2012-STD_64                                                                                                                   :
:               : WIN_LATEST                                                                                                                        :
:               : WIN_LATEST_32                                                                                                                     :
:               : WIN_LATEST_64                                                                                                                     :
:   local disk(0) : 25,100                                                                                                                              :
:   local disk(2) : 25,100,150,200,300                                                                                                                  :
:   san disk(0) : 25,100                                                                                                                            :
:   san disk(2) : 10,20,25,30,40,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,350,400,500,750,1000,1500,2000                                                   :
:   san disk(3) : 10,20,25,30,40,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,350,400,500,750,1000,1500,2000                                                   :
:   san disk(4) : 10,20,25,30,40,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,350,400,500,750,1000,1500,2000                                                   :
:   san disk(5) : 10,20,25,30,40,50,75,100,125,150,175,200,250,300,350,400,500,750,1000,1500,2000                                                   :
:           nic : 10,10,100,100,1000,1000                                                                                                           :
:.................:.....................................................................................................................................:
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ejk's approach, if you want to get this in Java you would need to call the API directly.

To get a list of possible locations you would call SoftLayer_Product_Package::getAvailableLocations

There is no direct call to get every operating system option for virtual machines so you will have to parse them out from [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItems](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems) or [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getCreateObjectOptions](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions). The options returned from getCreateObjectOptions are specific to the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createObject method. If placing the order through SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder you will need to use the former method.